# Trying to implement lazyload 'fade in' but it doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I'm using this plugin to lazyload images on my site: https://github.com/verlok/lazyload/blob/master/demos/fade_in.html

Lazyload seems to initialise but I can't get the fade in effect as seen in the link above. The site I'm using it on is [deannoble.com.au](https://deannoble.com.au)

**In the html, i'm using data-src on images:**

```
<img data-src="images/thumb-4.jpg" class="img-fluid works" alt="img"/>
```

**My CSS is:**

```
img:not(.initial) {
    transition: opacity 3s;
}
img.initial,
img.loaded,
img.fluid,
img.works,
img.error {
    opacity: 1;
}

img:not([src]) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**and my js is:**

```
(function() {
    function logElementEvent(eventName, element) {
        console.log(Date.now(), eventName, element.getAttribute("data-src"));
    }

    var callback_enter = function(element) {
        logElementEvent(" ENTERED", element);
    };
    var callback_exit = function(element) {
        logElementEvent(" EXITED", element);
    };
    var callback_loading = function(element) {
        logElementEvent("⌚ LOADING", element);
    };
    var callback_loaded = function(element) {
        logElementEvent(" LOADED", element);
    };
    var callback_error = function(element) {
        logElementEvent(" ERROR", element);
        element.src = "https://via.placeholder.com/440x560/?text=Error+Placeholder";
    };
    var callback_finish = function() {
        logElementEvent("✔️ FINISHED", document.documentElement);
    };
    var callback_cancel = function (element) {
        logElementEvent(" CANCEL", element);
    };

    var ll = new LazyLoad({
        threshold: 0,
        cancel_on_exit: true,
        // Assign the callbacks defined above
        callback_enter: callback_enter,
        callback_cancel: callback_cancel,
        callback_exit: callback_exit,
        callback_loading: callback_loading,
        callback_loaded: callback_loaded,
        callback_error: callback_error,
        callback_finish: callback_finish
    });
})();
```

Any tips here would be great! Thank you.

Comment: Your css is missing initial styles for the image https://github.com/verlok/lazyload/blob/master/demos/fade_in.html#L26-L32

Comment: Thank you @MonteCristo. I also moved `img.fluid` and `img.works` to the initial `img` css declaration which fixed it entirely

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```css
//lazy load images
img[src=""],
img:not([src]) {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

img:not([src=""]) {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```